# No react-app folder in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs

I have installed `react-app` in the terminal. The web page is created in the browser but the `react-app` folder is not getting created in `VS Code`. Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1- if you are trying to open Visual Studio code through terminal then make sure you are in your project directory then type `code .` to open VS code.

2- you can directly open your project through VS code. Open VS code and go to file open and then open and choose your project.

Hope this will help.